# I cannot understand some c++ template code

Tags: c++

I am reading some codes but I cannot figure out how to understand the `TH_convert<Elements>::t()...`.

1. I have searched on google and found that `...` can be used in variable numbers of arguments like `printf(char **, ...)`. However, the following lines are different.
2. I have seen that someone declared a member function as `void test(...)`. Is that correct because the the function of variable arguments requires the first argument.

```
class TH_convert{
public:
    typedef std::tuple<Element> t;
};

template<typename... Elements>
class State{
public:
    typedef decltype(std::tuple_cat(typename TH_convert<Elements>::t()...)) t;
};
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Comment: I'm fairly certain `TH_convert<Elements>t()...` is a typo.

Comment: @Danh because OP meant to type `TH_convert<Elements>::t()...`, which makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll break it down piece-by-piece.

```
template<typename... Elements>
class State{
    //...
};
```

This defines a [variadic class template](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/) called state which takes an arbitrary number of template parameters. `State<int,bool>` is a valid specialization of it, as is `State<Foo,Bar,Baz,Qux>` and even `State<>`.

```
decltype(/*...*/)
```

[`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) is essentially replaced with the type of whatever expression you put in `/*...*/`.

```
typedef decltype(/*...*/) t;
```

This makes `t` a typedef for whatever the type of `/*...*/` is.

```
typename TH_convert<T>::t()
```

This creates an object of type `TH_convert<T>::t`, which is the same as `std::tuple<T>`, given that definition of `TH_convert`. You need `typename` because it is a [dependent type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

```
std::tuple_cat(typename TH_convert<Elements>::t()...)
```

This calls `std::tuple_cat` with `typename TH_convert<T>::t()` for every `T` in the parameter pack `Elements`. So for `State<int,bool>`, it is equivalent to:

```
std::tuple_cat(TH_convert<int>::t(), TH_convert<bool>::t())
```

For `State<Foo,Bar,Baz,Qux>` it's the same as:

```
std::tuple_cat(TH_convert<Foo>::t(), TH_convert<Bar>::t(),
               TH_convert<Baz>::t(), TH_convert<Qux>::t())
```

So, putting all that together:

```
typedef decltype(std::tuple_cat(typename TH_convert<Elements>::t()...)) t;
```

This makes `t` a typedef for the type of the result of `std::tuple_cat`ting together the result of `TH_convert<T>::t()` for each `T` in `Elements`.

Comment: Although I'm not sure why it wasn't `typedef decltype(std::tuple_cat(Elements()...)) t;`, TH_convert seems superfluous here

Comment: @Caleth I assumed that this was a simplified version, otherwise it could just be `using t = std::tuple<Elements...>;`.

Comment: ... Yeah, I didn't simplify enough there. Does smell of complex for its own sake